# Vector algebra question

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $ a,b,c$ be unit vectors such that $a\perp b$ and $c$ is inclined at an angle of $\theta$ to both $a$ and $b$.

How shall I prove that $$c=\alpha(a+b) + \beta(a+b)\;\;\text{where}\; \alpha=-\cos\theta \;\text{and}\;\beta = -\cos2\theta\quad?$$

Comment: Rather than "inclined" do you just mean that the angle between $a$ and $c$ and the angle between $b$ and $c$ are both equal to $\theta$?

Comment: @rschwieb-I don't have a clear picture either. It just said so.

Comment: If rschwieb's interpretation of the question is right, then there could be two vectors $c$ satisfying the requirements (or one, or none).

Comment: There's a typo here. I suggest that the second term should have $a\times b$. My interpretation of "inclined" is what @rschwieb wrote. But I don't agree with the $-$ in either formula. As Andreas just commented, there should be a $\pm$ in the coefficient of $\beta$. And if $|\theta|<\pi/4$, there is no $c$. And why is $c$ a unit vector?

Answer (score 0):

Consider in $\mathbb R^2$ the vectors $a=(1,0)$, $b=(0,1)$ and $c=(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ with $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$. The triple $(a,b,c)$ satisfies the hypothesis in your question, if I have correctly understood the concept of being "inclined" (I can be wrong! Please, give further details). But then your statement

$(\cos\frac{\pi}{4}, \sin\frac{\pi}{4})=c=-\cos\frac{\pi}{4}(1,1)-\cos\frac{2\pi}{4}(1,1)$

is not true, as we obtain ($\cos\frac{\pi}{2}=0$)

$(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1,1)$

Answer (score 0):

OK, the editing has made things worse. We're in $\mathbb R^3$. We have unit vectors $a$, $b$, and $c$, with $a$ and $b$ orthogonal. We write
$$c = sa+tb+u(a\times b).$$
By dotting with $a$ and $b$, we find $s=t=\cos\theta$. Since $\|c\|=1$, we have 
$$1=s^2+t^2+u^2=2\cos^2\theta+u^2,$$
so $u^2=1-2\cos^2\theta=-\cos 2\theta$. Finally, 
$$c=(\cos\theta)(a+b) \pm \sqrt{-\cos 2\theta}(a\times b).$$
Comment: As should be clear on geometric grounds, we need $\pi/4\le\theta\le\pi/2$ to get solution(s).